# Fields to be covered for compliance data masking

Tags: masking, data-masking

I am into building a compliance checkup document for data masking.
Name of compliance--> Fields to be masked-->Type of masking
e.g.
PCI DSS --> “Mask PAN when displayed (the first six and last four digits are the maximum number of digits to be displayed).

From where can I get the list of attributes for all the major compliance's like PCI, PII, HIPAA etc

I will use the same as source of reference.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From where can I get the list of attributes for all the major compliance's like PCI, PII, HIPAA etc??

Are you asking what type of information to be masked?

it depends on transaction type that you are getting, i don't know what type of side (provider/payer/thridparty-broker).  it varies by the compnay to company. if it is HIPAA for sure u gonna deal with 820,834,835,837.

Please provide more information.